# Adding Google Play Services library dependency causes failure to generate R.java

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I followed 
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
to setup a library project (in eclipse) and then added this library project as a dependency in my Android project. (properties->Android->Add)
It caused the build to not create R.java without any specific error and caused thousands of compilation errors (references to class R).

Comment: You should post the answer to your problem as an answer (instead of as part of the question), and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that if I change the order of library dependencies, this problem goes away. (Google Play Services library must be the first dependency in my project). Not sure why.

I am posting this (a) for others and (b) to know why.